# xml file was showing error in" <context:annotation-config/> "tag

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations, javabeans, lifecycle

while implementing bean lifecycle using annotations, faced a issue where my xml file was showing error in" context:annotation-config/ "tag .
i added:

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>`
```

still the the annotations @PreConstruct and @PreDestroy were not applied.

Simply add this to your configuration file.

```
`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"`
```

and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then simply add this to your configuration file.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
```

And in the java bean add

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
```

for using annotation @PreDestroy and @PostConstruct
You can also try hovering over the annotations and look what imports you are missing out.
Hope this helps!